# How to do map[u].push_back(v) (c++) in java?

Tags: java, c++, generics, dictionary, stl

In C++ if i declare map STL like this way `map< int ,vector < int > > m;` i could use this in `m[u].push_back(v);` in this manner. But how can I do this in Java ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int u = 0;
    int v = 1;
    Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = 
        new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    if (map.get(u) == null) { // Add a List if they key is null.
        map.put(u, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
    // Add v to the List at u.
    map.get(u).add(v);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question this should be what you're looking for.

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>();
map.put(0, new ArrayList<Integer>());
Integer someInt = 1;
map.get(0).add(someInt); //get arraylist and add to back.
```